# Как сделать POST-запрос к Yandex Translate API?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, яндекс-переводчик

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect?key=trnsl.1.1.20150402T131655Z.e753695703b45806.bda2fd6beb5bd56a62f0034352aaebbdba3f0952&text=hey";
    let res = fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })

        });
});
```

Это мой запрос. Выглядит как `GET`, верно? Проблема в том, что если я пытаюсь хоть один параметр запихнуть в Body, то запрос возвращает `Bad Request`.

```
let url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
let res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({key:"trnsl.1.1.20150402T131655Z.e753695703b45806.bda2fd6beb5bd56a62f0034352aaebbdba3f0952", lang:"en-ru", text:"hello"}),
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })

    }).then(ok=>console.log(ok.json()));
```

В [документации](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/detect-docpage/#JSON) есть пример, где сам `URL` со всеми параметрами, кроме `text`. Окей, я и так сделал. Все равно не работает:

```
let url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20150402T131655Z.e753695703b45806.bda2fd6beb5bd56a62f0034352aaebbdba3f0952&lang=en-ru";
let res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({text:"hello"}),
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })

    }).then(ok=>console.log(ok.json()));
```

Задал body в явном виде, так же как у них в [документации](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/detect-docpage/#JSON):

```
let url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20150402T131655Z.e753695703b45806.bda2fd6beb5bd56a62f0034352aaebbdba3f0952&lang=en-ru";
let res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body:'text:hello',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })

    }).then(ok=>console.log(ok.json()));
```

Можете проверить в консоли. Что я делаю не так? Я так понимаю, что в POST параметры должны быть в body, а не в строке запроса?

И это вроде бы не ограничение в кол-ве символов - до 1млн я еще точно не дошел.

Comment: @VicrotGorban а ключ вы свой вставили?

Comment: @danilshik, запрос таки работает в виде get. Ключ не мой, с моим то же самое.

Comment: @VictorGorban вы не поверите, но ошибка всего одна. Надо писать body:'text=hello'. Знак равно вместо двоеточия.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, да уж. Для такого и нужен SO)

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, и json.stringify разделяет двоеточием, ясное дело

Comment: ошибка была в том, что контент-тип стоял для формы, а слал ты json

Comment: @Grundy, а какой надо? text/plain не работает, Application/json тоже

Comment: @VictorGorban, правильно, потому что судя по справке яндекс как раз ожидает обычную форму. То есть нужно было менять не контент тип, а само значение которое ты отправлял. Примерно к этому ты и пришел, только не понял что и почему. Подробнее про контент типы для метода POST можно посмотреть [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря @УстьянцевБорис, ответ для моего случая был найден крайне просто: 
Надо писать body:'text=hello'. Знак равно вместо двоеточия.

Update:
Благодаря @Grundy, я нашел полный ответ.

Вот рабочий пример:

```
let url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
let res = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body:'key=trnsl.1.1.20190419T144929Z.9a7ce55bcbc0ab3a.7b061e1931fe57955befd67ab7151772bed63f0f&lang=en-ru&text=hello',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })

    }).then(ok=>console.log(ok.json()));
```

Для `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, тело нужно задать в виде `key1=value1&key2value2`.

Про контент-типы для POST: [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)